# How to read a folder containing multiple csv file using os.listdir

Tags: pandas

```
from os import listdir

filepaths = [f for f in listdir(r"C:\Users\arshad\Downloads\Python Assingment 3\Prob1\batchwiselist") if f.endswith('.csv')]
print(filepaths)

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv,filepaths))
```

Getting Error:

> file not exists

but when I print `filepath` the file is there in it.

Comment: `listdir` returns file names not the full path. you need to add your directory to the file name.

Comment: You should just accept the answer by Mayank if it worked by clicking on the tick Mark in grey rather than posting a comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement:

```
filepaths = [f for f in listdir(r"C:\Users\arshad\Downloads\Python Assingment 3\Prob1\batchwiselist") if f.endswith('.csv')]
```

This returns only the filenames in output **without the absolute path**.

Like this:

```
In [344]: [f for f in listdir(r"/Users/zomato/") if f.endswith('.txt')]                                                                                                                                     
Out[344]: ['t1.txt', 't.txt', 'airlines.txt']
```

So, you need to add absolute path to the filenames, like this:

```
In [345]: ["/Users/zomato/"+ f for f in listdir(r"/Users/zomato/") if f.endswith('.txt')]                                                                                                                   
Out[345]: ['/Users/zomato/t1.txt', '/Users/zomato/t.txt', '/Users/zomato/airlines.txt']
```

**For your case, do this:**

```
abs_path = "C:\Users\arshad\Downloads\Python Assingment 3\Prob1\batchwiselist\"

filepaths = [abs_path + f for f in listdir(r"C:\Users\arshad\Downloads\Python Assingment 3\Prob1\batchwiselist") if f.endswith('.csv')]
```

Comment: @ARSHADANSARI Please let me know if the answer worked.